# A version of `w` which skips to the next underscore

Tags: neovim, cursor-motions

I frequently work with code style which asks that many non-class symbols use `snake_case` -- Python, Ruby, and C especially. If I have a symbol like `longfirstpart_longsecondpart`, I'd like to be able to jump to the underscore in the middle *à la* `w` skipping to the next `word`.

Is there a built-in shortcut or `init.vim` variable for this kind of behaviour?

Answer (score 10):

This can be done very easily with the `iskeyword` option. From `:h iskeyword`

```
                        *'iskeyword'* *'isk'*
'iskeyword' 'isk'   string (Vim default for MS-DOS and Win32:
                        "@,48-57,_,128-167,224-235"
                   otherwise:  "@,48-57,_,192-255"
                Vi default: "@,48-57,_")
            local to buffer
            {not in Vi}
    Keywords are used in searching and recognizing with many commands:
    "w", "*", "[i", etc.  It is also used for "\k" in a |pattern|.  See
    'isfname' for a description of the format of this option.  For C
    programs you could use "a-z,A-Z,48-57,_,.,-,>".
    For a help file it is set to all non-blank printable characters except
    '*', '"' and '|' (so that CTRL-] on a command finds the help for that
    command).
```

So add this to your `.vimrc`:

```
set iskeyword-=_
```

and that should work for you.

Comment: While this does work in terms of just skipping forward, it completely breaks my colorscheme if I add an underscore or a slash as a keyword. Any way around that?

Comment: what colorscheme is this?

Answer (score 6):

I would simply use `f_`, but that means I know I want to move to the underscore instead of abstractly to the next word.

You can repeat the last `f` with `;`, and both `f` and `;` accept a count.

Comment: Not only does `;` go forward again but `,` goes backward. Sorta like hitting `N` instead of `n` after a search.

Answer (score 2):

There are exist two plugins for the improving experience to move through camelCase and snake_case.

1. The first one is he [camelcasemotion plugin](https://github.com/vim-scripts/camelcasemotion), defining the additional commands, normally prepended with a comma. But this one is old and unmaintained for many years.
2. The second one is actively developed, and uses completely different approach - [vim-wordmotion](https://github.com/chaoren/vim-wordmotion). It redefines the word boundaries, so all default commands will work as is, just within new rules:

```
CamelCaseACRONYMWords_underscore1234
w--->w-->w----->w---->w-------->w->w
e-->e-->e----->e--->e--------->e-->e
b<---b<--b<-----b<----b<--------b<-b
```